# Showing the language of TMs that halt on a decidable set of words is not in RE

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I need to show that the following language, L = {$\langle M \rangle$ | The set of words which M halts on is decidable}, is not recursively enumerable. In the instructions they advise thinking of a reduction that is similar to the one used in the proof for Rice's Theorem in Sipser's 3rd edition (page 243). I couldn't think of a proper proof by myself. I assume L $\notin RE\cup CO-RE$ so there's no point in trying to prove $\bar{L}$ is in RE to show L is not in RE. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reduction from coHALT (given a Turing machine, determine whether it doesn't halt on the empty input) to $L$. Given a Turing machine $M$, construct a new Turing machine $M'$ which acts as follows:

- Run $M$ on the empty input.
- If $M$ halts, interpret the input as a Turing machine and run in on the empty input.

If $M$ doesn't halt on the empty input, then the set of words on which $M'$ halts is the empty set, which is decidable, and so $M' \in L$. If $M$ does halt on the empty input, then the set of inputs on which $M'$ halts is HALT, which is not decidable, and so $M' \notin L$.